# Check button is selected using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have HTML like this:

```
<input data-errorqtip="" aria-invalid="false" id="checkbox-1371-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-checkbox x-form-cb" autocomplete="off" hidefocus="true" type="button">
```

In UI it is showing like checkbox. How to check if it is selected?
I am using bellow code but is not working.

```
if (!field.isSelected()) {
    field.click();
}
```

Comment: ---- above means tag open and close

Comment: Here the `type` is `button` and you expect it to be `checkbox` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !driver.findElement(By.id("idOfTheElement")).isSelected() )
{
     driver.findElement(By.id("idOfTheElement")).click();
}
```

Comment: Hey Mudit in my question code "field" is nothing but "driver.findElement(By.id("idOfTheElement"))".

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are using EXTjs.  And while it renders as a checkbox, EXT does not set the input element value to selected so selenium won't know about it.

You will need to use selenium's ExecuteScript method to run javascript against EXT to determine if the item is selected or not.

I'd dig up the code, but I use EXT, Selenium, and C# and I have a feeling the syntax is going to be a bit different between the two, but the above is the general steps you will need to go through to get the result you are looking for.